# How to loop java with incorrect input

Tags: java, loops

I'm currently learning how to code and I'm facing a bit of a problem, and I was hoping someone could help me out. Currently, Im creating a program that prompts for military status and shows appropriate discounts, but I would like it to loop if the answer isn't one of the given options.

This is my code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    char milID = ' ';
    char status = ' '; 

    String validMilitaryID = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Do you have a valid military ID?");
    milID = validMilitaryID.charAt(0);

    Scanner valid = new Scanner(System.in);


    if (milID == 'Y') {
      System.out.printf("%n Are you Active Duty, Retired, or a Dependant?");
        status = valid.nextLine().charAt(0);
    } else if (milID == 'y'){
      System.out.printf("%n Are you Active Duty, Retired, or a Dependant?");
        status = valid.nextLine().charAt(0);
    }else{
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, you are currently ineligible for a Military Discount");
      System.exit(0);
    }


    if (status == 'A'){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congratulations! You are eligible to recieve a 15% discount!");
    } else if (status == 'R'){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congratulations! You are eligible to recieve a 13% discount!");
    }else if ( status == 'D'){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congratulations! You are eligible to recieve a 10% discount!");
    } else {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! That was not a valid answer.");
    }




   System.exit(0);
  }//END MAIN
```

If anyone is able to help, can you explain the process as well. Since I am new to Java I would like to learn rather than just have a fix. 
Thank you!!

Comment: read about while loops

Comment: What do you know about loop ?

Comment: use do...while(expression)

Comment: Just curious. Why not use `JOptionPane` where you have `System.out`?

Comment: ... or  `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` instead of the `Scanner` (that you don't close)

Comment: I personally think you should try to solve this yourself. If you write down your logic and try to follow what you are doing and what you are trying to do, it will benefit you later.

Comment: ^ It's more for a learning purpose, just so I can learn to use each in their own way for different prompts.

Comment: I read up on while loops, and I am seeing examples for use with numbers, but I cannot find anything for char's or given options.

Answer (score 0):

1) you may call your input as well as your if code into a while loop

2) maybe use a switch instead of if..else if

something from the logic such as:

```
boolean checkInput = true;
while (checkInput) {
  // now get your input... not coded

  switch (milId) {
    case "y","Y": bla bla, break;
    case "x","X": bla bla, break;
    otherwise: bla bla, break;
}}
```

3) use a variable for your account value; you could code this with a lookup

Comment: I integrated these into my code, and Im not sure what the issue is, but it will not restart to loop when something incorrect is put in for status.     while (!verify);
    {case 'd':
        System.out.printf("%n Congrats %s discount!", discount.get(3));
        verify = false;
      break;
      
      default: System.err.println("That is not a valid status.");

Answer (score 0):

An integral part of Java (or programming in general) is missing from your code, and that is the "while loop". I do not know how much knowledge of Java you have so far, but a while loop repeats what's in its block of code until a requirement is met. If you are adding a feature that repeats the survey if the wrong input is given, a while loop at the beginning of your conditionals is what you need.

**Pseudocode**

```
create variable called correctAnswer
Do you have a military id? Enter y or Y if yes, any other key for no
if yes, correctAnswer = 1
if no, correctAnswer = 0 and while loop is skipped 

while correctAnswer = 1
{
   Are you active, retired, etc?
   If yes, what is your status?

   if A, R, or D is given, display congrats message. correctAnswer = 0 //end 

   if anything other than A, R or D is given, then correctAnswer = 1 //repeat 
}
```

The while loop in the second block of conditionals keeps repeating the loop until a correct answer is given.